# Show/Hide multiple divs based on selected option - almost there

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have the following code which I have pieced together from posts on here, and its working so far...

```
<label>Number of Colours</label>
<select id="main-select">
    <option value="1">1 Colour</option>
    <option value="2">2 Colours</option>
    <option value="3">3 Colours</option>
    <option value="4">4 Colours</option>
</select>

<div class="colour-option" id="colour1">
<label>1st Colour</label>
<select>
    <option value="colour1">Colour One</option>
    <option value="colour2">Colour Two</option>
    <option value="colour3">Colour Three</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="colour-option" id="colour2">
<label>2nd Colour</label>
<select>
    <option value="colour1">Colour One</option>
    <option value="colour2">Colour Two</option>
    <option value="colour3">Colour Three</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="colour-option" id="colour3">
<label>3rd Colour</label>
<select>
    <option value="colour1">Colour One</option>
    <option value="colour2">Colour Two</option>
    <option value="colour3">Colour Three</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="colour-option" id="colour4">
<label>4th Colour</label>
<select>
    <option value="colour1">Colour One</option>
    <option value="colour2">Colour Two</option>
    <option value="colour3">Colour Three</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Together with the following jQuery...

```
var showDiv = function (colour) {
$('.colour-option').hide();
$('.colour-option:lt(' + colour + ')').show();
};

$('#main-select').change(function () {
showDiv($(this).val());
}).change();
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/UWUYN/5/
and thats exactly how I want it to work, however, my #main-select is generated for me, and as such the values cannot simply be, 1,2,3,4. They form part of a Shopify cart and the values my #main-select is outputting is "1 Ink Pad", "2 Ink Pads", "3 Ink Pads" & "4 Ink Pads". Is there a simple way to edit the JS to take this into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), if the format of the values are going to be like that:

```
showDiv(parseInt(this.value, 10));
```

This will get only the integer part from the value, e.g `1` from `1 Ink Pad`.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UWUYN/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks! Can I trouble you to just explain what that's doing? I just want to understand what its doing differently (I'm very new to JS) Thanks. - EDIT, ahhh! You've already explained it! Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Is it possible to somehow render the inputs that are not being shown disabled or clear their values? One pitfall with this, is if I select "four colours" and choose one in each dropdown, and I then change my mind and select "2 colours", it hides the last two selects, but their values are kept. This means they are being passed to the cart.

Comment: @shorn Have you tried using something like `$('.colour-option').val("").hide();` instead of `$('.colour-option').hide();`

Comment: Thanks you, I tried this but it doesn't have any effect. It still keeps the same value as before?

Comment: Just thinking about it, but would this be because the `.colour-option` is targeting the div, and not the actual select?

Comment: OK, I have changed the code as per this example http://jsfiddle.net/UWUYN/11/ and it seems to work. I targeted the selects to set the value to "". Now as you can see from the fiddle, when you make a new selection from the main select, it basically resets all the dropdowns to "". Is there a way to only target the selects that are being hidden. That way if a users makes a select on dropdown 1, it remain selected even if they change the number on the main select. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

First, just a recommendation, IMO, adding and removing a class that determines hidden is better than using .hide and .show

That aside.  You could use the selects selectedIndex or the options index property rather than it's value.

```
var showDiv = function (colour) {
  $('.colour-option').hide();
  $('.colour-option:lt(' + colour + ')').show();
};

$('#main-select').change(function () {
  showDiv($(this).prop('selectedIndex') + 1);
}).change();
```

Comment: Do you happen to have an example that would adds/removes a hidden class?

Comment: In your css add .hidden { display:none; }  Instead of .hide() use $('colour-option').addClass('hidden')  instead of .show() you can use .removeClass('hidden') or .toggleClass('hidden'), either works.